# secItemAdd keep return -50 error in swift

Tags: ios, keychain

Keep getting -50 when trying to add an item in security chain.

```
    var query = [String:AnyObject]()
    query[kSecClass as String] = kSecClassGenericPassword
    query[kSecAttrAccount as String] = "a"
    query[kSecValueData as String] = "b"
    let result = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil);
```

result is -50.  Can not figure out why, need help.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe the value for the `kSecValueData` key needs to be an NSData, not a String or NSString. Try encoding your string to data (with e.g. UTF-8 encoding). Untested snippet:

```
query[kSecValueData as String] = "b".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

For future reference, the error code -50 corresponds to `errSecParam`, which the SecBase.h header documents as meaning: "One or more parameters passed to a function were not valid." If you see this error again, try changing the values that you're passing in with your query dictionary.

Comment: I have another question regarding keychain, can you help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053049/seccopyerrormessagestring-gives-use-of-unresolved-identifier-in-swift

Comment: in swift 4: `"b".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)`

Answer (score 7):

Slightly updated Swift 5 version of add to/remove from keychain functionality:

```
@discardableResult
func addToKeychain(_ value: Data, tag: Data) -> Bool {
    let attributes: [String: Any] = [
        String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tag,
        String(kSecValueData): value
    ]

    var result: CFTypeRef? = nil
    let status = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, &result)
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        print("Successfully added to keychain.")
    } else {
        if let error: String = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) as String? {
            print(error)
        }

        return false
    }

    return true
}

@discardableResult
func removeFromKeychain(_ value: Data, tag: Data) -> Bool {
    let attributes: [String: Any] = [
        String(kSecClass): kSecClassKey,
        String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): tag,
        String(kSecValueData): value
    ]

    let status = SecItemDelete(attributes as CFDictionary)
    if status == errSecSuccess {
        print("Successfully removed from keychain.")
    } else {
        if let error: String = SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil) as String? {
            print(error)
        }

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
let value: Data = "key".data(using: .utf8)!
let tag: Data = "com.test.key".data(using: .utf8)!

removeFromKeychain(value, tag: tag)
addToKeychain(value, tag: tag)
```