# Keychain react-native shared with Swift today widget

Tags: ios, swift, react-native-ios

We have a react-native application that uses [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) library in this way [(like in this issue)](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/36#issuecomment-302151678):

```
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
 try {
            Keychain.setInternetCredentials(
                'device-id',
                'RANDOMDATA',
                DeviceInfo.getUniqueID().toString(),
                { accessGroup: 'org.reactjs.native.example.myreactapp'})
                .then(() => console.log('Done'))
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("error save", err)
        }
```

I would like to be able to retrieve this data in my today widget made in swift, I would need to know the storage key for that.
Below is the way I'm supposed to get it back on the widget:

```
let itemKey = "device-id"
let keychainAccessGroupName = "3P********.org.reactjs.native.example.myreactapp"

let queryLoad: [String: AnyObject] = [
      kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
      kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey as AnyObject,
      kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
      kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
      kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainAccessGroupName as AnyObject
    ]

    var result: AnyObject?

    let resultCodeLoad = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
      SecItemCopyMatching(queryLoad as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
    }

    if resultCodeLoad == noErr {
      if let result = result as? Data,
        let keyValue = NSString(data: result,
                                encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {

        // Found successfully
        print("device-id : ", keyValue)
      }
    } else {
      print("Error loading from Keychain: \(resultCodeLoad)")
    }
```

The code below come from [this blog](https://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/)

But it doesn't work. As you may have noticed I need to pass the device-id to the widget because unlike Android the UUID often changes and we get a different ID on each part which prevents the widget from working properly

Comment: Are you able to retrieve `device-id` on the javascript side, after you have set it in the keychain? Perhaps this could help with retrieving your code on the swift side https://stackoverflow.com/a/37539998/5508175

Answer (score 0):

Change this code in APP：

```
{ accessGroup: 'org.reactjs.native.example.myreactapp'})
```

to

```
{ accessGroup: '3P********.org.reactjs.native.example.myreactapp'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

In my react native app:

```js
import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';


export function saveToKeychain(key: AllowedKeychainKeysEnum, value: string) {

  return Keychain.setInternetCredentials(
    key,
    key,
    value,
    {
      accessible: Keychain.ACCESSIBLE.ALWAYS,
      accessGroup: KEYCHAIN_GROUP,
    },
  );
}
```

Using this function then might look like this:   `saveToKeychain(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME, accessToken)`

Now in your swift app:

```swift
  func readFromKeychain(key: String) -> String? {
      let query = [
          kSecClass as String : kSecClassInternetPassword,
          kSecAttrAccessGroup as String : keychainGroup,
          kSecAttrServer as String : key,
          kSecAttrAccount as String : key,
          kSecReturnData as String : kCFBooleanTrue!,
          kSecMatchLimit as String : kSecMatchLimitOne
      ] as [String : Any]
      
      var dataTypeRef: AnyObject? = nil
      let status: OSStatus = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &dataTypeRef)
      
      if status == noErr {
          let text = String(data: dataTypeRef as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
          return text
      } else {
          return nil
      }
    }
```

Make sure you create a keychain group. This guide can show you how to do it: https://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/.

Also ensure that everywhere in your code where your reference your keychain group make sure to prefix it with your app id.