# Trying to add item to Keychain using SecItemAdd() results in -50

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

When I try to add an item to the macOS keychain using `SecItemAdd()` with the parameter `kSecAttrSynchronizable` in a commandline Swift application, I get the error `-50 (One or more parameters passed to the function were not valid)`. It works correctly if I remove `kSecAttrSynchronizable`. I've tried using [KeychainAccess](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) and I've tried to do it manually (using the keychain services API provided by macOS), the result is the same.

```
import Foundation
let account = "username"
let password = "password".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

var query: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
                        kSecAttrAccount as String: account,
                        kSecAttrServer as String: "nabeelomer.me",
                        kSecAttrSynchronizable as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
                        kSecValueData as String: password]

let status = SecItemAdd(query as CFDictionary, nil)
print(status)
```

Is there maybe an undocumented permission that the application needs?

Swift 4.0, macOS 10.13.3, Xcode 9.1

Comment: been a while but have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051482/secitemadd-keep-return-50-error-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

`kSecValueData` needs to be `Data`, not `String`

try

`kSecValueData: password.data(using: .utf8)!`